# CMake target collision in multi module project

Tags: cmake

At the beginning I had a bunch of CMake projects handled separately: each one had its own target for generating documentation called **doc**. Now I need to wrap all these projects with a super-project: the problem is that super-project compilation fails complaining that exist multiple targets with the same name **doc**.

The simple solution I thought is to prepend each **doc** target with the name of the project, but it does not satisfy me.

I would like **not** to have to use `make projectX_doc` when compiling a single sub-project and to have a global target `make doc` for generating the documentation of all projects when compiling super-project.

Are my requests possible? Is there any mechanism to handle target collision?

Comment: Can you please give an example of such a `doc` target? Are we talking about `add_custom_target()` calls?

Comment: See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/ALLOW_DUPLICATE_CUSTOM_TARGETS.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well each subproject could verify if there are inside a super project with:

```
if("^${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}$" STREQUAL "^${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}$")
  set(IS_SUBPROJECT FALSE)
else()
  set(IS_SUBPROJECT TRUE)
endif()
```

Thus in your projects CMakeLists.txt you can do:

```
if (NOT IS_SUBPROJECT)
  set(DOC_TGT doc)
else()
  set(DOC_TGT ${PROJECT_NAME}_doc)
endif()
add_custom_target(${DOC_TGT} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ...
```

note: you can merge both snippets to avoid `IS_SUBPROJECT` variable

In your super project CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_custom_target(doc EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
  DEPENDS projectX_doc projectY_doc...
```

So when configuring/building each sub project standalone you have
 `make doc` otherwise when you are in your super project target doc become a meta target...

note: You can also use this trick to modify default options etc...
e.g. gflags:
https://github.com/gflags/gflags/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L126

https://github.com/gflags/gflags/blob/master/cmake/utils.cmake#L61
https://github.com/gflags/gflags/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L163